# Flex/Air - Capture Windows 7 auto maximize event?

Tags: apache-flex, air

I'm currently working on an Air application that can be maximized/restored/minimized.

The max/min/restore button events are handled fine. In Windows 7 however, if the user 
is resizing the app and the mouse reaches the top of the screen, it can automatically 
maximize the Air application. The application's resize buttons do not reflect this.

Is there a way to listen for this happening within the Air application?

I know I can listen for a resize event, and could then try to figure out if the screen 
was maximized by windows. This would be messy and unreliable based on my investigations though.

**UPDATE**

Found a solution:  I can listen to the NativeWindowDisplayStateEvent.DISPLAY_STATE_CHANGE event and set the title bar buttons at that point if event.afterDisplayState == NativeWindowDisplayState.MAXIMIZED

Comment: On my Windows 7 unit; I am unable to maximize my browser window by resizing the window to the top of the screen.  It does size the window from top to bottom; but not left to right.  [Clicking and dragging the title bar to the top will maximize it]  Why does it matter how the screen was maximized?

Comment: The Max button was not changing to a Restore button after maximized automatically by Windows 7. I can listen to the NativeWindowDisplayStateEvent.DISPLAY_STATE_CHANGE event and set the title bar buttons at that point if event.afterDisplayState == NativeWindowDisplayState.MAXIMIZED